# Garage Service Door Threshold / sill advice

Tags: water, garage-door, threshold

I have a garage service door that leads out to a concrete slab that is higher than the garage floor. Needless to say, any rain and the garage floods. I am looking to replace the door and solve for the height difference. Any advice gratefully received! Thanks.

[image]

Comment: How much roof overhang? Is there a gutter?

Comment: overhang is about 2 feet and there is no gutter. I am hoping to add a gutter as well as fix the door.

Comment: what is holding you building elevated step outside, maybe a inch high

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean. It is a concrete slab, it is not connected to the foundation but butted right up against it. I don't know why it was built higher than the garage floor. Seems silly it was done this way!

Comment: to prevent water coming in, pore some concrete as a step in front of the door, about 1 inch high that would create a barrier

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the slab seems unlikely, though it's the only really good fix. Rent a big honking floor grinder and grind it down, with a path for water to flow *away* from the door. Or break it up and pour a new one at the right level.

You can make as much of a fix as is practical short of that without replacing the door, unless you want to replace the door anyway.

Cut out the (apparently) rotten bottom of the frame and rebuild with pressure-treated wood, including a higher threshold in the space between the front of the door and the slab, heavily sealed - or make that from masonry, such as laying a line of bricks there. You can cut the door shorter and extend that under the shortened door, or just build it up in front of the door.

If you want to raise the whole door opening, you will likely need to move the door header framing up as well, and that can be difficult. Tall people would appreciate the effort.

Comment: if you want to move the door up you should also move the whole wall up, else the water will just come in under the wall.   removing the  outdoor slab along the whole length of the wall looks like the easiest to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could install a linear drain in the exterior slab just outside the garage door. This would allow any water that hits this slab to run into the drain and flow from there to... wherever you choose.